# How to display fragment in viewpager, in fragment class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a activity which contains of navigation drawer, in that class my navigation items point to fragment classes, In one of the fragment classes i am using a dynamic view pager to display items, but how can i use fragment manager of fragment class as a argument of view pager which needs fragment argument of fragment activity or activity, Need some solutions.

Comment: can post some codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm doing something similar right now. I only have the the ViewPager below the navigation drawer, but if you have a more complicated layout the same principal should work.

To start, I have the activity layout (most of this was generated by Android Studio)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.you.yourapp.YourActivity">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/your_container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.example.you.yourapp.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The activity uses the FragmentManager to swap in another fragment that contains the ViewPager into the FrameLayout

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your);

    ...

    Fragment fragment = YourFragment.newInstance(Bundle args);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your_container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

The Fragment that has the ViewPager is simple

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/your_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

in YourFragment.java implement your FragmentPagerAdapter(you could do this as an inner class, but I ran into problems with static allocation, plus this is cleaner)

```
public class YourFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private ViewPager mPager;

    public YourFragment() {

}

public static TaskFragment newInstance(Uri uri, String outlineText) {
    TaskFragment fragment = new YourFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    //set args
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_your, null);
    mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_view_pager);

    TaskPagerAdapter adapter = new TaskPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}

...

private class YourPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public YourPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count; //however you get the count
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //set the arguments for your page
        return PageFragment.newInstance(args);
    }

}

}
```

ETA:
So now implement a custom interface for your navigation drawer callbacks

```
...
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
}

...

@Override
public void onClick(View view) { //whatever your click listener is
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentSomehow(); //get your fragment
    mCallbacks.onNavigationItemSelected(fragment);
}

...

public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(Fragment fragment);
}
```

Now have YourActivity implement this interface

```
public class YourFragment extends Activity
        implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks
{

...

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManeger()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.you_container, fragment)
            .commit();
    }
...
}
```

I think this is what you mean to do.
Hope this helps

Comment: no @seiterm i am not facing such problem, its what i have explained above. anyways thanks.

Comment: Ok I think I see. One minute